# How to forward a command parameter?

Tags: macros

I am defining a new command and a flag with:

```
\newcommand{\setActorsStyle}[1][1]{
  \ifnum#1=1
     \setActorsStyleColor{}
  \else
     \setActorsStyleBW{}
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\flag}{0}
```

Calling the command as following with

```
\setActorsStyle[\flag{}]{}
```

results in compilation error `Missing = inserted for \ifnum` as if the parameter given to `\ifnum` is not an integer. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Note you should have a `%` at the end of every line that ends with `{` or `}` (but not `1`) otherwise use of this command will generate white space in the printed output.

Comment: The `{}` trick should be used only when you want to ensure that following spaces are not gobbled, so usually for commands that do typesetting.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't have the empty braces after `\flag`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\setActorsStyle}[1][1]{
  \ifnum#1=1
     \typeout{ONE!}
     %\setActorsStyleColor{}
  \else
     \typeout{NOT ONE!}
     %\setActorsStyleBW{}
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\flag}{0}

\setActorsStyle[\flag]{}
```

Here I have disabled the two macros whose definition I do not have, and used `\typeout` to display a message in the terminal, to show that the modified code works.

The problem with the original version is that `#1` expands to the number 0 followed by an empty group. This combination is not a number, so it breaks the syntax for `\ifnum`. You could get away with `\flag{}` if you did

```
\ifnum1=#1
```

because then the expansion would yield `\ifnum1=0{}` which is ok.

Comment: Thanks ! Can you please explain why in this particular case I shouldn't use the empty braces ?

Comment: @ManuelSelva with the braces it is `\ifnum0{}=1` which is a syntax error.

Comment: @ManuelSelva --- I have edited my answer.

Comment: With `\ifnum#1=1` the space token caused by the end-of-line is ignored. With `\ifnum1=#1` it wouldn't when `#1` is `\flag{}`. To cope with this you should have `\ifnum 1=#1\relax`